# Haskell parsing prefix evaluation

Tags: function, parsing, haskell

I'm struggling with this code.

```
import Data.Char (isDigit)
data Ast = V Int | Neg Ast | A Ast Ast | M Ast Ast deriving (Show,Eq)

parseE ("+":xs) = let (e1,r1) = parseE xs; (e2,r2) = parseE r1 in (A e1 e2, r2)
parseE ("*":xs) = let (e1,r1) = parseE xs; (e2,r2) = parseE r1 in (M e1 e2, r2)
parseE ("-":xs) = let (a,r) = parseE r in (N a, r)
parseE ("(":xs) = let (a,")":r) = parseE r in (a,r)
parseE (x:xs) = (V (read x :: Int), xs) 

eval xs = parseE xs
```

When my input is something like: `* + 1 2 * 3 + 7 - 2`

I want the ouput to be: `((1+2)*3)*(3*(7-2))` which should show `45`

When I load my file in haskell, I get this error :

```
:load "newf.hs"
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( newf.hs, interpreted )

newf.hs:6:44: error: Data constructor not in scope: N :: Ast -> Ast
  |
6 | parseE ("-":xs) = let (a,r) = parseE r in (N a, r)

  |                                            ^
Failed, 0 modules loaded.
```

Comment: Your grammar is ambiguous, how do you parse +12345?

Comment: @n.m. You don't. His grammar just doesn't support unary pluses. And this grammer is not ambiguous.

Comment: @Shersh It supports prefix binary plus, which is what I'm asking for.

Comment: What functions?

Comment: The grammar doesn't mention whitespace at all, so `+12345` could be parsed as `+`/`1`/`2345`, `+`/`12`/`345`, `+`/`123`/`45`, or `+`/`1234`/`5`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the data constructor `N` is not in scope.  Data constructors are the things on the right-hand side of `data` statements.  In your example, `V`, `Neg`, `A`, and `M` are data constructors.  "Not in scope" means "not defined where it was used".

It looks like you wrote `N` where you meant to write `Neg`, or vice versa.  Fixing your `data` statement to read:

```
data Ast = V Int | N Ast | A Ast Ast | M Ast Ast deriving (Show,Eq)
```

allows the program to compile.

There are still a few bugs in the program.  For example, the following gets stuck in a loop:

```
> parseE (words "* + 1 2 * 3 + 7 - 2")
(M (A (V 1) (V 2)) (M (V 3) (A (V 7) (N  -- freezes
```

because of the statement:

```
let (a,r) = parseE r in (N a, r)
```

which introduces an unintended recursive definition -- you're defining `r` as the result of calling `parseE r`, which causes an infinite loop.  You have a similar problem in the case that tries to handle parentheses.