# Haskell - Calculate string "let X = 3 in + X X"

Tags: haskell, recursion

Hi I need help with calculating a type. The whole program is suppose to take a string, parse it, and at the end, calculate a value. The string I start with can be like this: "`let X = + 1 2 in * X 2 - X`". When I parse it, I will get this: "`Let (Vari X) (Sum (Lit 1) (Lit 2)) (Mul (Vari X) (Lit 2)))`". At this moment, I can parse expressions like this "* + 2 3 * 2 + 6 - 2" and the previous. But I can not calculate the previous expression, "`let X = + 1 2 in * X 2 - X`". If someone could point me in the the right direction I would be happy, cause right now, I really don't know how I would make this work. Thanks

Code:

```
data Chara = A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z deriving (Eq, Show)

data Number = Single Int | Many Int Number deriving (Eq, Show)

data Expr = Lit Int | Sub Expr | Sum Expr Expr | Mul Expr Expr | Vari Chara | Let Expr Expr Expr 
    deriving Show


--Want to calculate this
--Let (Vari X) (Sum (Lit 1) (Lit 2)) (Mul (Vari X) (Lit 2)))


calculate :: Expr -> Int 
calculate (Sub a) = let e = calculate a in (-e)
calculate (Sum a b) = let e = calculate a 
                          r = calculate b 
                      in (e+r)          
calculate (Mul a b) = let e = calculate a 
                          r = calculate b 
                      in (e*r)
calculate (Lit a) = a
```

Comment: Are you sure it should be `Let Expr Expr Expr` and not `Let Chara Expr Expr`? (Not that this is completely unreasonable, but it is a bit more tricky and probably not worth for an educational aspect).

Comment: Are [you guys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584907/haskell-parsing-input-functions) getting assignments for the same class?

Comment: I am working on an assignment. Don't know about the other guy.

Comment: @leftaroundabout No, it's acutally gonna be Expr, cause Expr could be Vari which is a Chara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to perform *variable substitution* in your AST. I.e. you need a function

```
substitute :: (Chara, Expr) -> Expr -> Expr
```

which, given a pair of *variable to substitute* and *expression to substitute it with* will traverse the tree and perform that substitution. That basically means: if you find a `Vari`, just replace it with the substitution. If you find anything with subexpressions like `Sum a b`, recurse down into those subexpressions and then rebuild the operator with the results, i.e.

```
        Sum (substitute s a) (substitute s b)
```

Then the `calculate (Let var subst expr) = ...` is a pretty straightforward invocation of the `substitute` function.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got something that starts to work! :D

Answer (score 1):

Works like a charm

```
calculate :: Expr -> Int 
calculate (Sub a) = let e = calculate a in (-e)
calculate (Sum a b) = let e = calculate a 
                          r = calculate b 
                      in (e+r)          
calculate (Mul a b) = let e = calculate a 
                          r = calculate b 
                      in (e*r)
calculate (Let a b c) = calculate (substitute (getCharaFromExpr a) b c)
calculate (Lit a) = a       


substitute :: Chara -> Expr -> Expr -> Expr 
substitute x y (Lit a) = Lit a
substitute x y (Vari a) | x == a = y
                        | otherwise = Vari a 
substitute x y (Sum a b) = Sum (substitute x y a) (substitute x y b)
substitute x y (Mul a b) = Mul (substitute x y a) (substitute x y b)
substitute x y (Sub a) = Sub (substitute x y a)
substitute x y (Let a b c) = Let (substitute x y a) (substitute x y b) (substitute x y c)
```